# Maybe burninate the [adjustable] and the [adjustment] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Maybe these two tags are a bit too broadly used and should be burninated: [adjustable](/questions/tagged/adjustable), [adjustment](/questions/tagged/adjustment)

Comment: "What adjustments should I make so that my list adjusts properly?"  Tag, please!

Comment: @Jamal [auto-adjustable]? :D

Comment: BTW, does it exist the term "robo-tagger" as a SO meme? If not, I find it missing!

Comment: [Could be somewhere here!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that in some implementation(s) of Common Lisp there is the concept of an [*adjustable array*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_a.htm#adjustable) and there were two questions related to that, but I rettaged them with [adjustable-array](/questions/tagged/adjustable-array).

Apart from that, I see no obstacle to burninate those tags.